# Renaming only certain part of a file name

Tags: powershell

I need to write a powershell script to rename only a certain part of a file name.

`MTR` needs to be changed to `MTE`, only the `R` needs changing,  all others letters/numbers needs to stay the same.

Original file name 
`FILEORIG.MTR001`

File needs to be changed to 
`FILEORIG.MTE001`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide code I cant get you a ready to go script but this is the command you are after once you locate the file and pipe it..

```
<# Your Code Here, Probably a Get-ChildItem #> | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "MTR","MTE"}
```

Comment: Awesome.. thanks for the quick response Drew.... got it working and file name changed to how I want it.

Thank you so much..